# Calculate how many members are 18 or older in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a Table1 (memberslist) with a column birthdays and i want to count how many members are older than 18.

cell P2 has a date 1/1/2023

`=COUNTIFS(Table1[Birthday];(YEAR(P2)-YEAR(Table1[@Birthday]))>18)`

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

So, calculate the age based on the current date, then show 1 if over 18:

[image]

NOW() is the current date and time so it will be correct next year.

YEARFRAC() works out the age,

IF() puts a 1 if over 18.

Added a few to show under 18:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the YEAR function returns the number of the year as (2023). But the comparison is made in how excel stores dates.

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[Birthday];"<"&DATE(YEAR(P2)-18;1;1))
```